# how to only append new data in ajax request django?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

hello guys so i have this ajax script that get the data from my backend view it works but it only empty the data and replace it with the new one but what i want to do is that i want this ajax request to only get the new data that is not in my div task if the data is in my div task i want to tell it to don't append it i try to do it here:

```
def task_admin_manager(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        data_task = task_admin_form.objects.all()
        list_id_task = []
        for data in data_task:
            data = data.id
            if data is not in list_id_task and task_admin_form.objects.filter(id__exact=data).exists():
                id_fix = data_task.objects.filter(id__exact=data)
                list_id_task.append(id_fix)
                for id_task in id_fix:
                    dict_id_task = {}
                    dict_id_task['username'] = id_task.username.username
                return Httpresponse(json.dumps(dict_id_task))
```

here it will returm the response

```
    function update_task_manager(){
            var append_increment = 0;
            var add_data = " "
            $.ajax({
                method:"GET",
                url:"taskadmin",
                data:{'append_increment': append_increment},
                success:function(response){
                    add_data = add_data +'<li class="admin-task">'+'
                    <div class="admin-image">'+'
                        <img src="{%static "image/dedek.jpg" %}" alt="image-admin">'+'
                    </div>'+'
                    <div class="task-admin">'+'
                        <div class="admin-name-due">'+'
                            <label>'+response.username+'</label>'+'
                            <small>Due: {{form_tasks.task_tenggat}}</small>'+'
                        </div>'+'
                        <div class="task-subject-task">'+'
                            <label>{{form_tasks.subject}}</label>'+'
                            <div class="button-task">'+'
                                <div clas="detail-task">'+'
                                    <button id="tampilkan-detail-task" value="{{form_tasks.id}}">Detail Task<i class="fa fa-file" style="margin-left:5px"aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'+'
                                </div>'+'
                                <div class="button-status">'+'
                                    <button><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'+'
                                    <button><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'+'
                                </div>'+'
                            </div>'+'
                        </div>'+'
                    </div>'+'
                </li>'
                $('task-manager').append(add_data)
            }
            })
        }
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            update_task_manager();
        },5000)
```

because i used return it will only get one data because it will break the loop if i put the return outside the loop it will still print one data because the dict will keep appending the data with same key but different value, can someone give me a tips? or how they do it if the cases like this? thanks here is my code.

```
    def task_admin_manager(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            data_task = task_admin_form.objects.all()
            return render(request,"task_mager.html",{"form_task":dict_id_task})
```

main.html

```
<div class="content-task">
   <ul id="task-manager">
   </ul>
</div>
```

task_mager.html

```
{% load static %}
{% for form_tasks in form_task%}
<li class="admin-task">
    <div class="admin-image">
        <img src="{%static 'image/dedek.jpg' %}" alt="image-admin">
    </div>
    <div class="task-admin">
        <div class="admin-name-due">
            <label>{{form_tasks.username}}</label>
            <small>Due: {{form_tasks.task_tenggat}}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="task-subject-task">
            <label>{{form_tasks.subject}}</label>
            <div class="button-task">
                <div clas="detail-task">
                    <button id="tampilkan-detail-task" value="{{form_tasks.id}}">Detail Task<i class="fa fa-file" style='margin-left:5px'aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-status">
                    <button><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function update_task_manager(){
    var append_increment = 0;
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url:"taskadmin",
        data:{'append_increment': append_increment},
        success:function(response){
            console.log("this is sucess function");
            console.log(response);
            $("#task-manager").empty()
            $("#task-manager").append(response);
        }
    })
}
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    update_task_manager();
},5000)
```

Comment: what does `response` returns ? Also ,where is `task-manager` div ?

Comment: sorry for that ill update the code now

Comment: i update my code

Comment: the response return the data from taskadmin that got from the task_mager.html and the ajax will append the data that it got to the task-manager id

Comment: Okay so what value is unique to all the `li` that can be used to compare ?

Comment: id of the task that in class admin-task

Comment: you mean `{{form_tasks.id}}` ? Also what does response has unqiue ? because here you need to compare the `response` with the data in `ul` ?

Comment: sorry to reply late but i somehow make it work by add list comprehension